# Is it wise to use a variable iteration count in Rfc2898DeriveBytes?

Tags: c#, .net, security, encryption, hash

It's a rather theoretical question. Suppose you have a password from which you want to derive the main key. Is it secure to hash the password first with SHA256, parse and truncate the computed bytes to an integer then use the modulo operator so that it's contained in a range (i.e. 1000-3000) and use this integer as a parameter for the Rfc2898DeriveBytes in .NET?

The main goal of this is to make the iteration count variable. Am I losing any entropy by doing so?

Here is the C# code for randomizing the iteration count:

```
        #region Constant Definitions
        private const int HASH_SIZE = 512;
        private const int ITERATIONS_LOWER_BOUND = 1000;
        private const int ITERATIONS_UPPER_BOUND = 2500; //must exceed lower bound
        private const uint SALT_SIZE = 256;
        #endregion

        public static int RandomizeIteration(byte[] Key) {
            if (ITERATIONS_UPPER_BOUND <= ITERATIONS_LOWER_BOUND) {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Iteration parameters are incorrectly configured.");
            }
            //Hash the key using SHA256 algorithm
            byte[] HashedKey = SHA256.ComputeHash(Key);
            long HashSum = Math.Abs((BitConverter.ToInt64(HashedKey, 0)));

            Console.WriteLine("Iterations: " + (HashSum % (ITERATIONS_UPPER_BOUND - ITERATIONS_LOWER_BOUND) + ITERATIONS_LOWER_BOUND));

            return (int) (HashSum % (ITERATIONS_UPPER_BOUND - ITERATIONS_LOWER_BOUND) + ITERATIONS_LOWER_BOUND);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no benefit in using a variable iteration count. For verification, the number of iterations must be known anyway (it is not a secret), so it can be used for brute forcing also. You only vary the amount of time needed for calculating the hash, and this is not desirable, the time should be choosen depending on your server's performance.

If your intention is to add a secret to the hashing process (so an attacker has to guess the number of iterations), there are better ways. A good way to add a server side secret, is to encrypt the password_hash.

Comment: But does it not increase security against side-channel attacks?

Comment: @Crossfire - To be able to brute-force a PBKDF2 you need an offline attack (a stolen database, brute-forced on a local machine). In this scenario, the number of iterations is known, and it is obvious that you need more time and energy to do more iterations. The only thing you could guess is the number of iterations, but this you already know. Since all but the first iteration is hashing an input of a fixed length, it seems unlikely that a side channel attack is applicable at all with PBKDF2.